# Проблемы с кодировкой в Spring 3 MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Здравствуйте. Пытаюсь сделать вот что:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/something")
@ResponseBody
public String helloWorld() {
    return "Русский текст";
}
```

Страница принимает Примерно это:

```
??????? ?????
```

На странице кодировка UTF-8. Но даже если бы она и другой была бы, то были бы в любом случае не вопросительные знаки. Посоветуйте, пожалуйста, как исправить ситуацию.

Дополню вопрос: Очень странно получилось в такой ситуации:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/something")
public ResponseEntity<MyCls> helloWorld() {
    MyCls cls = new MyCls();
    cls.setStr("Русский текст");

    HttpHeaders h = new HttpHeaders();
    return new ResponseEntity(cls, h, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Сейчас сработало так, как я и ожидал:

```
{"str":"Русский текст"}
```

У спринга что, на тип String аллергия?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Похоже, это известная проблема ([аналогичный вопрос на SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3616359/who-sets-response-content-type-in-spring-mvc-responsebody), [баг в джире](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-6443)), решается она несколькими способами:

- так, как указал @Nofate - использовать ResponseEntity с соответствующими заголовками;
- добавить конвертер в `hw-servlet.xml` (код ниже);
- забабахать свой конвертер с блекдж... (как [тут](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?81858-ResponseBody-and-UTF-8)).

Сконфигурированный конвертер:

```
<bean class = "org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="messageConverters">
        <array>
            <bean class = "org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter">
                <property name="supportedMediaTypes" value = "text/plain;charset=UTF-8" />
            </bean>
        </array>
    </property>
</bean>
```

В ответе на SO говорится, что второй метод не сработает с `mvc:annotation-driven` - не знаю, у меня заработало и с ним.

---

UPD. Ага, с `mvc:annotation-driven` не заработает, если поставите конвертер после этого объявления.

Comment: собственно нарыл все то же самое, однако с конверторами у меня что-то никак не срастается на практике.

Comment: СУПЕР! Спасибо огромное!

Comment: @Антон Мухин, если у вас заработает Hello World с вышеупомянутыми конверторами, вас не затруднит скинуть мне на почту? Хочу до конца разобраться в вопросе, но своими силами пока не выходитю

Comment: Письмо пошло...

Answer (score 2):

В `web.xml` добавить сам фильтр:

```xml
<!--encoding filter-->
<filter>
    <filter-name>characterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>characterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

В параметрах подключения к базе, добавить следующий код:

```xml
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dataBaseName<b>?characterEncoding=UTF-8</b>
```

Answer (score 1):

Проверьте на всякий случай кодировку самого файла с исходником. Знаки вопроса - верный признак попытки интерпретировать cp1251-строку в качестве UTF-строки.

--

UPD1. Все, что пока получилось, это:

```
public ResponseEntity<String> preview(HttpServletResponse response) {
HttpHeaders h = new HttpHeaders();
h.add("Content-type", "text/html;charset=UTF-8");
return new ResponseEntity<String>("Привет мир",h ,HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Comment: ???�??????  - вот результат работы программы после изменения файла исходника на UTF-8. Т.е. чуть поменялось, а положительного результата нет. URIEncoding у меня  UTF-8.

Comment: Если есть возможность - предложил бы выложить проект на какое-нибудь файлохранилище, чтобы можно было посмотреть, что там и как.

Comment: Хм. Проект очень большой. Если Вы не против, я сделаю небольшой хэлоуворд, и отправлю Вам проект в архиве почтой

Answer (score 1):

Помогло включение параметров в application.properties

```
server.servlet.encoding.charset=UTF-8
server.servlet.encoding.force=true
```

Answer (score 0):

Добавлю от себя еще. Если вы используете обработку ошибок @ExceptionHandler и вам нужен русский текст, например в ошибках sql от бд на фронте и передаете их например в формате json, то также нужно добавить в ..-servlet.xml:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver">
    <property name="messageConverters">
        <array>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter">
                <constructor-arg index="0" name="defaultCharset" value="UTF-8"/>
                <property name="supportedMediaTypes">
                    <list>
                        <value>text/plain;charset=UTF-8</value>
                        <value>text/html;charset=UTF-8</value>
                        <value>application/json;charset=UTF-8</value>
                        <value>application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8</value>
                    </list>
                </property>
            </bean>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
                <property name="supportedMediaTypes">
                    <list>
                        <value>text/plain;charset=UTF-8</value>
                        <value>text/html;charset=UTF-8</value>
                        <value>application/json;charset=UTF-8</value>
                        <value>application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8</value>
                    </list>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </array>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Ну и maven зависимости:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

Подтверждаю, работает с `<mvc:annotation-driven/>`, объявленном после бинов. Может кому пригодится.
[Мой пост по этой теме](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/574536/%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9-utf-8-%D0%B2-spring-mvc-%D0%B2-response-exceptionhandler/574555#574555)

Answer (score 0):

Надо поправить аннотацию и вписать `produces`:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/something", produces = "text/plain;charset=UTF-8")
```

Ответ [найден тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5649329/utf-8-encoding-problem-in-spring-mvc). Проверил, работает.

Answer (score -1):

Если используется Tomcat, то в `server.conf` (по-моему так файл называется) надо поправить коннектор, по которому вы работаете - добавить `URIEncoding="UTF-8"`.

Comment: У меня GlassFish. Попробую сейчас найти, как там поменять это.

Comment: Не, не помогло.

Comment: Если jsp страница обычно помогает это   <%@ page session="false" isELIgnored="false" pageEncoding="UTF-8" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"  %>

Answer (score -2):

В дескрипторе приложения необходимо добавить фильтр:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filterclass>
          org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filterclass>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
```

Comment: Да, и еще неплохо было бы увидеть определение ViewResolver'а.

Comment: Тоже неверно (

Comment: @Антон, вы промаппили фильтр, указанный @a_gura? Вот так: <filter-mapping><filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name><url-pattern>/*</url-pattern></filter-mapping>

Comment: Неа, попробую сейчас.
Ну все! Я в полном ступоре! Все-таки, видимо, либо у меня чудесный компьютер, либо у Spring действительно на класс String, в котором текст на кириллице, аллергия!!! И с <filter-mapping> также приходят на страницу вопросы. Тут, по-видимому, проблема не в сервере, и не в файле web.xml. Тут, видимо, проблема со спрингом. Может, какие-то дополнительные настройки надо сделать? Вроде все сделал по учебнику, все правильно. Создал новый проект, чтобы проверить, что получится. Результаты одни и те же.

Comment: А можете и мне на почту прислать тестовый проект?

Comment: Я не знаю Ваш адрес эл.почты. А так, с удовольствием пришлю)

Comment: (А, в профиле пользователя не видно адрес): gooyozh@gmail.com, пожалуйста.

Comment: Насчет "чудесный компьютер". 

Недавно у меня был в чем-то похожий случай. Поставил на новый комп Win 7. Вывод консольных программ (Java тоже) идет в юникоде с БОМ. Каждый символ (что русский, что ASCII, что в файл, что на экран) **два байта**.

Убрал в regional settings русский (поставил US) для консольных программ. Перегрузил. Опять поставил там же русский. Перегрузил. 

О, **чудо**, вывод пошел нормальный, однобайтный в cp-1251. Программы на Java тоже заработали, как и раньше.

Может и у Вас, что-то подобное ?

Comment: Фильтр нужно замапить (`<filter-mapping>`) и это должен быть самый **первый** фильтр в web.xml.