# Русский (utf-8) в spring mvc в response @ExceptionHandler

Tags: java, sql, исключения, spring-mvc, utf-8

Всем привет! Столкнулся с проблемой, поиски ни к чему не привели.
Обрабатываю ошибки sql из БД в своих контроллерах и отправляю на фронт:

```html
 @ExceptionHandler(DataException.class)
 @ResponseBody
 public ResponseEntity<String> handleException(DataException e, HttpServletResponse response) {
  log.error(e);
  response.setContentType("application/json;charset=UTF-8");
  response.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
  response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
  if (e.getRootCause() instanceof SQLException) {
   SQLException s = (SQLException) e.getRootCause();
//   return CommonUtil.getErrorResponse(ErrorToResponse.getJsonSqlError(s.getMessage(), s.getSQLState()));
   return new ResponseEntity<String>("ТУТ РУССКИЙ ЯЗЫК!", HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
  } else {
   log.error(e);
   return CommonUtil.getErrorResponse(ErrorToResponse.getJsonError(e.getMessage()));
  }
 }
```

Но вместо русского получаю "?????? ??? ???".
Уже добавил :

```html
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter">
  <property name="messageConverters">
   <array>
    <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter">
     <constructor-arg index="0" name="defaultCharset" value="UTF-8"/>
     <property name="supportedMediaTypes">
      <list>
       <value>text/plain;charset=UTF-8</value>
       <value>text/html;charset=UTF-8</value>
       <value>application/json;charset=UTF-8</value>
       <value>application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8</value>
      </list>
     </property>
    </bean>
</bean>
 <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver">
  <property name="messageConverters">
   <array>
    <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter">
     <constructor-arg index="0" name="defaultCharset" value="UTF-8"/>
     <property name="supportedMediaTypes">
      <list>
       <value>text/plain;charset=UTF-8</value>
       <value>text/html;charset=UTF-8</value>
       <value>application/json;charset=UTF-8</value>
       <value>application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8</value>
      </list>
     </property>
    </bean>
   </array>
  </property>
 </bean>
```

Но ничего не помогает!
К слову в :

```html
 @RequestMapping(value = "/Services/getData", method = RequestMethod.POST)
 @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
 public ResponseEntity<String> getData(@RequestParam(value = "param", required = true) String param, HttpServletRequest request, HttpSession httpSession) {
  return execute(param, request, httpSession, CRUDServiceDAO.Action.GET);
 }
```

без проблем приходит русский язык, проблема возникает только в @ExceptionHandler(DataException.class) 
Очень надеюсь на вашу помощь!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну вот и решил вопрос, не успев задать. Может кому пригодится.
Добавил в

```html
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver">
<property name="messageConverters">
<array>
<bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
 <property name="supportedMediaTypes">
  <list>
   value>text/plain;charset=UTF-8</value>
   <value>text/html;charset=UTF-8</value>
   <value>application/json;charset=UTF-8</value>
   <value>application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8</value>
  </list>
 </property>
</bean>
...
```

И нужные зависимости в maven :

```html
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
  <version>2.8.3</version>
</dependency>
```

После чего я наконец получил желанный русский язык на клиенте.